# Not receiving all posted data from PDF form to php

Tags: php, forms, pdf, acrobat

I am sending data from a PDF form with a submit button in HTML format to a php script for further processing. The form has many fields arranged in rows like this:

a group of radio buttons named: `row[i][answer]`, then inline some text fields named: `row[i][ov], row[i][plo], row[i][plcv], row[i][pls], row[i][plx]` (where i is incremented from 0 to 100)

On submit i post all this data to a php script like this:

```
$row = $_POST['row'];
```

Now the problem is that for some reason i receive all data but `row[i][answer]` and `row[i][plx]`...those 2 fields are being completely ignored and i cannot find a reason for this.

I did `<pre><?php  print_r($row); ?></pre>` and there it is all the data but those 2 fields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ov] => Some text.
            [plcv] => N/A
            [plo] => Art. 4 
            [pls] => N/A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ov] => Some text.
            [plcv] => N/A
            [plo] => Art. 10 
            [pls] => N/A
        )
    . . .
```

There should be also `[answer]` and `[plx]` but they are completely missing.

I also did it with `file_get_contents("php://input");` and same result, [answer] and [plx] are missing.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: So we would need to see the code that 1) Creates this data, 2) recieves this data

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)